# Average Large Array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, average

I'm trying to average a large (~1.000.000 dataset) vector. I already have the data like this:

```
struct data {
    std::string alias;
    double id;
    std::string timestamp;
    double value;
};
```

Now I want to average every all values for one day. The timestamp is something like this: "20-NOV-12 10.52.21.260000000 AM". I only care for the substr(0,8), which contains the part of the string describing the day. 
Currently I have this:

```
typedef std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, size_t, double>> days; 
days&& average_days(const std::vector<data> _d)
{
  days ret;
  for(auto &d: _d) {
      bool found = false;
      int count = 0;
      double val= 0.0;
      for(size_t i = 0; i < ret.size(); i++) {
          std::string day = d.alias.substr(0,8);
          auto t = ret[i];
          if (std::get<0>(t) == day) {
             found = true;
             std::string ali = std::get<0>(t);
             size_t coun = std::get<1>(t) + 1;
             double val = std::get<2>(t) + d.value;
             ret[i] = std::make_tuple(ali, coun, val);
         }
         val = std::get<2>(t);
      }
      if (!found){
          ret.push_back(std::make_tuple(d.alias.substr(0,8) ,1, val));
      }
}
return std::move(ret);
}
```

This gives me an evil exception ( evil exception =segmentation violation). I just can't get my head around this thing. 
What is the best and fastest way of doing this?

Comment: *"This gives me an evil exception"* - Does it?  I was unaware of `std::evil_exception`.  Interesting. How about posting the actual error and where it occurs?

Comment: What kind of evil exception?  From which line?  What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: You are returning a reference to a local object...

Comment: This question is unclear; you use loaded phrases (like “obviously” when it’s really nothing of the sort, or “evil” without describing what the frack you actually mean) and just assume that everybody knows what you mean by “average” over a complex type. Clear the question up, it’s unanswerable at the moment, and your code does more to confuse than to help (for instance, why does it take its argument by value and returns a dangling rvalue reference?). Oh yes, and 1M isn’t actually that large either.

Comment: don't return `std::move`; it interferes with the built-in optimisation of the compiler

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear. I tried debuggind this for the last 12 hours.

Comment: Why are you voting you close: "not a real question"? Non of the points describing the "not a real question" case match here.

Comment: Just to clarify: the rvalue comes from me desperately trying to get this to work. The function should get the right thing in the end I just looked for the error there and this is probably the 10th iteration of rewriting this. And to me 1M is rather big considering the fact, that the program is being run a couple of times a day for more than just one dataset.

Comment: @Kay Really? What about “It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete … and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.” Spot-on, if you ask me. (Incidentally, the edits made the question slightly better.)

Answer (score 5):

Your program very likely has **Undefined Behavior**. Whatever is causing the exceptions you are experiencing, here:

```
    days&& average_days(const std::vector<data> _d)
//  ^^^^^^
    {
        days ret;
        // ...
        return std::move(ret);
    }
```

You are returning a reference to a local object. By the time the variable which receives this returned reference is assigned, the object this referenced was bound to will be dead because of going out of scope.

Thus, you are basically returning a dangling reference, and dereferencing that will inject Undefined Behavior into your program.

Just return your object this way (and mind the fact that you probably want to pass a vector with a million entries **by reference** rather than by value!):

```
    days average_days(const std::vector<data>& _d)
//  ^^^^                                     ^ 
//  No rvalue reference!             Pass by reference!
    {
        days ret;
        // ...
        return ret;
    //         ^^^
    //         No std::move()!
    }
```

Comment: Just tried that: same thing. I think it is the algorithm that crashes the program.

Comment: @BenediktWutzi: Actually I realized that it shouldn't be the reason for the exception, although it doesn't feel correct.

Comment: actually I just thought about it too. I take care about that with the "if(!found)..."